# Create widget with customview

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, custom-view

I'd like to use several CustomViews in my appwidget and thus want to create a bitmap out of every CustomView.
So i tried that with

```
Bitmap customBitmap = customView.getDrawingCache(true);

remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, customBitmap );
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: can you provide more info? exact code?

Comment: i now included the original code

Comment: How does this custom view look like?

Comment: It's basically a path

Comment: @Johannes so everything is drawn on a canvas?

Comment: yes, it is drawn on a canvas... would it be better to get the path, then draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes, it is drawn on a canvas

I would do something like this:

```
public Bitmap createCustomView(){

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // draw on the canvas:
    // ...

    return bitmap;
}
```

and then set the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView`:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, createCustomView() );
```